# Can someone create a Model of this person for my new Project?

Tags: modeling

So this is the scene:

[image]

The idea is to make a Scene of a Sleeping Paralysis. As you can see, the doors seem to go crazy and the Wall is also kind of strange. I plan to add many more things but at the moment, i try to figure out the perfect Horror lighting and i am testing different lights.

I would like to have this Girl form the Movie "lights Out" in the final Render:

[image: Diana from Lights Out FRONT]

[image]

[image]

So my question is if there is anybody who could do that for me. I am really bad at character modeling and i think it would be a cool idea.

Thanks !

Comment: I know you can buy 3D characters on some website, I'm sure they have some zombie girls

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a request for work, not a question about using Blender.

Comment: @RayMairlot
Well you are right but i just asked for help. Where do i have to post a request ?

Comment: You could post the job in one of the job forums on [BlenderArtists](https://blenderartists.org/c/jobs).

Answer (score 2):

There are free tools available to create humanoid models - for example, the MakeHuman project (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MakeHuman) or Manuel Bastioni add-on that allows you to create characters within Blender (see http://www.manuelbastioni.com/manuellab.php)